# How does this Boolean array work?

Tags: java, arrays, boolean

I don't understand how this code works. The problem is find the next year after a given year with distinct digits.

```
public Main(){
    try{
        BufferedReader in;
        in = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in)); //Used for CCC
        String year = (in.readLine());
        for(int i = Integer.parseInt(year)+1;; i++){
            String f = Integer.toString(i);
            boolean [] characters = new boolean[10];
            boolean unique = true;
            for(int x = 0; x < f.length(); x++){
                if (characters[f.charAt(x) - '0']){
                    unique = false;
                    break;
                }
                else{
                    characters[f.charAt(x)-'0'] = true; 
                }
            }   
            if (unique){
                System.out.println(f);
                return; 
            }
```

Specifically how does this if statement work?

```
if (characters[f.charAt(x) - '0']){
```

what does checking a boolean do here? Shouldn't they all be defaulted to false? and why is the -'0' there? Sorry for the noob question.

Comment: Have you tried to set breakpoints or otherwise debug the code to try to understand it yourself?

Comment: `Shouldn't they all be defaulted to false?` - yes they are, but you are not checking `characters[x]` you are checking `characters[f.charAt(x)-'0']`

Comment: @cricket_007 I've tried but I'm pretty novice at java so I don't really know how to use a debugger I'll watch some videos on it, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I suspect you missed the `else` part.  If it does not find the position is true, it is set to true  (`characters[f.charAt(x)-'0'] = true; `), so that later you know it is the second time encountering a character if you find the position is already true

Answer (score 1):

The expression

```
f.charAt(x) - '0'
```

will return a number between 0 and 9 depending on the digit at position `x` in the String `f`.  Hence the code will set a boolean flag at each of the 10 digit positions in the array, and if a digit occurs more than once, then it will report false and break out of the inner loop to consider the following year.

Comment: What's a boolean flag? I googled it but I can't really tell is it just setting a boolean as false or true?

Comment: @I.Lav Yes, it is just setting `true` in the `characters` array for each number it encounters.  If it finds a number which it has already seen, then it would reject that year.

Answer (score 0):

`characters` is a boolean array of 10 elements and stores whether a given input character (which are supposed to be limited to decimal digits) appears more than once in the input.

Character codes for digits are in the 0x30 - 0x39 range; `f.charAt(x)` returns the character at index `x` in the input and then `- '0'` transforms it into a number in the range of 0 - 9 - an index into the boolean array.

When a character is first found, its slot is set to `true`; when it's found again, `unique` is set to `false` to indicate that the input has duplicate characters.